# expanding rows using banded variable

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to expand rows using banded variables. Below is the input data and required output data. Basically want to expand my rows using tonnage, which, in the input dataset has a wider width.

I tried using expand.grid and splitstackshape but unable to proceed. Please help.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to create master of your bands. You can create a custom function & do `lapply`. I have used a `for` loop so that the steps are easy to debug & follow.

```
library(tidyverse)
bands <- c(0, 7.5, 12, 20, 40, Inf)
# Master df of all the bands
df_bands_master <- cbind(bands, c(bands[-1], bands[1])) %>% 
  as_tibble() %>% 
  slice(1:nrow(.) - 1) %>% 
  select(lb = bands, ub = V2)
# Your input df
df <- tibble(
  Key = c("FDE", "GED"),
  Tonnage = c("0-40", "7.5-40")
)
# Your output df
df_final <- c()

for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {
  
  temp_row <- df %>% slice(i)
  
  temp_full_band <- as.numeric(str_split(temp_row$Tonnage, pattern = "-") %>% pluck(1))
  
  temp_min_band <- bands[which(temp_full_band[1] >= bands)] %>% pluck(length(.))
  temp_max_band <- bands[which(temp_full_band[2] <= bands)] %>% pluck(length(.))
  
  df_final <- df_final %>% 
    bind_rows(
      df_bands_master %>% 
        filter(lb >= temp_min_band, ub <= temp_max_band) %>%
        unite(Tonnage_Split, c("lb", "ub"), remove = T, sep = "-") %>% 
        mutate(Key = temp_row$Key))
}

df_final %>% 
  select(Key, Tonnage_Split)
```

[image]

You can mutate to make it `40+` I will leave that for you. Hint: Use mutate in combination with `ifelse` inside the for loop while binding the rows.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a suggestion. I wrote a function with three parameters: start, end, and cutoffs. Then, run this function by row. The key is to use `cut()` to generate the string for the bands.

```
library(tidyverse)
dat <- data.frame(key = c("FDE", "GED"), tonnage = c("0-40", "7.5-40"))

split_numbers <- function(start, end, cutoffs) {
  cutoffs <- cutoffs[between(cutoffs, start, end)]
  
  cut(1, cutoffs) %>% 
    levels() %>% 
    str_remove_all("\\(|\\]") %>% 
    str_replace(",", "-") %>% 
    c(paste0(end, "+"))
}

dat %>% 
  separate(tonnage, c("start", "end"), sep = "-") %>% 
  group_by(key) %>% 
  summarise(
    tonnage_split = list(split_numbers(start, end, c(0, 7.5, 12, 20, 40)))
  ) %>% 
  unnest(tonnage_split)

# # A tibble: 9 x 2
#   key   tonnage_split
#   <chr> <chr>        
# 1 FDE   0-7.5        
# 2 FDE   7.5-12       
# 3 FDE   12-20        
# 4 FDE   20-40        
# 5 FDE   40+          
# 6 GED   7.5-12       
# 7 GED   12-20        
# 8 GED   20-40        
# 9 GED   40+
```